# ReactiveForm with ng-template

Tags: angular

I have a "base" component that contains a form. Inside that form there are two form controls I would like not to define inside but use `ng-container` along `*ngTemplateOutlet` instead. When I do that, I am getting an error: `formGroup expects a FormGroup instance.`. The message is correct as the form control must exists inside a form group. I thought hat I could pass context via `ngTemplateOutletContext` and solve the issue, but it just does not work. To visualize what I am doing:

For the "base" component:

```js
selector: 'app-component-a',

carFormGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
 type: [''],
 model: [''],
 color: [''],
 country: [''],
 revenue: ['']
});

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="carFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="save()">
 <div id="grid-cell-car-manufacturer-details">
 <ng-container
   [ngTemplateOutlet]="carDetailsTemplate"
   [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{carFormGroup: carFormGroup}"></ng-container>
 </div>
</form>
```

and the template for the second component (using the base one):

```html
<ng-template #bComponentOwnTemplate let-carFormGroup>
 <form [formGroup]="carFormGroup">
  <ul class="manufacturer-details">
    <li><input type="text" formControlName="country"></li>
    <li><input type="text" formControlName="revenue"></li>
  </ul>
 </form>
</ng-template>

<app-component-a
[carFormGroup]="bComponentOwnTemplate"></app-component-a>
```

But it does not work, still getting `formGroup expects a FormGroup instance.`. Is what I am trying to do even possible ? Can I have a form in "base" component and define some of its controls via `ng-template` in another component ?

Comment: I'm really not sure, but I'd give it a shot on: You defined your context as `{carFormGroup: carFormGroup}` and you're trying to access it inside your `ng-template` with `let-carFormGroup`. For what I've done with `ngTemplateOutletContext` I'd either change to `let-carFormGroup="carFormGroup"` or the context to `{$implicit: carFormGroup}`, so I could use plain `let-carFormGroup`.

Comment: holy moly, I was passing context wrong. You are absolutely right. Thank you Sir. If you add that as an answer I will accept it as it solves my question.

Comment: Hi, really glad I could help. Created an answer with the content of my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you defined your context as

```
{carFormGroup: carFormGroup}
```

and you're trying to access it inside your `ng-template` with

```
let-carFormGroup
```

For what I've done with `ngTemplateOutletContext` I'd either change to

```
let-carFormGroup="carFormGroup"
```

or change the context to

```
{$implicit: carFormGroup}
```

so I could use plain `let-carFormGroup` to access it.

Glad I could help.